# Spring integration:Header value router not getting invoked everytime

Tags: spring-integration

We are using `header-value-router`. Configuration:

```xml
<int:header-value-router input-channel="accountSummeryRequest"
        header-name="word"
        default-output-channel="accountSummeryRequest"
        resolution-required="false">
    <int:mapping value="xx" channel="accountSummeryRequest" />
    <int:mapping value="yy" channel="newRequestChannel" />
</int:header-value-router>

<int:service-activator id="accountServiceActivator" 
        input-channel="accountSummeryRequest"
        output-channel="accountSummeryResponse" 
        ref="serviceGatewayAdapter" 
        method="requestHandler" 
        send-timeout="60000"/>

<int:service-activator id="caRequestActivator" 
        input-channel="newRequestChannel"
        output-channel="accountSummeryResponse" 
        ref="caServiceGatewayAdapter" 
        method="requestHandler" 
        send-timeout="60000"/>
```

now if i give word as `yy`,first time header-value-router `enter code here`is getting called and exact service activator,in this case  is `caRequestActivator` ,is called. But i try again with `word=yy` header-value-router is not getting called and request goes through `accountServiceActivator`. Alternate requests works correctly.

I don't know what's the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is around a `round-robin` dispatcher for `accountSummeryRequest` channel and its two subscribers: `<int:header-value-router>` and `accountServiceActivator`.

To fix it you should change the `input-channel` of that `<service-activator>` to some different channel. And, of course, don't fogtet to change the `<header-value-router>`
accordingly.